# Why does SO store questions and answers in the same table?

Tags: discussion

This is what I concluded from the id of questions and answers.

But why?

Answer (score 13):

Since you enjoy asking questions so much, I will answer your questions with more questions.

- What's the difference between a question and an answer?
- What fields does question have, that answer does not?
- Should similar items be stored together?

Comment: And so begins the overflow...

Comment: Since you like asking me questions,I'll just answer you here:
1.an answer doesn't have title,tags,viewed times
2.as above
3.the two objects have so many difference,how can store together?It'll spawn a lot of null.

Comment: An answer has a view count. You can see that by going to your profile and sort your answers by view count.

Comment: Ok...At least an answer doesn't have title and tags,right?

Comment: What if a stackexchange customer asks for tagging of answers? or titles in questions? IMHO they are similar enough to warrant the same table.

Comment: The tags must be stored in a thired table anyway.I can see there are huge amount of NULL for answer's title in the SAME table.

Comment: Nothing wrong with NULL values.  The only thing I'd do differently is that since they're using sql server 2008, they could use the new hierarchal data features. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290.aspx

Comment: So, you would create a separate and identical table with all duplicated columns minus one, because one type doesn't use that one column?

Comment: To sum up,an answer doesn't have tags,title,accepted answer,accepted time.How different will you think it's really different?

Comment: @Shore: the answer would be to normalize the data, not split it up arbitrarily. However, SO may well have a good reason for keeping their data somewhat denormalized. See: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001152.html