# Why did Stack Overflow put questions and answers in the same database table?

Tags: discussion, architecture, technology, database-design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does SO store questions and answers in the same table?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24537/why-does-so-store-questions-and-answers-in-the-same-table)

I took a look at SO's HTML. I noticed that the ID number of a given question was very close to its answers' ID numbers. Sometimes they were just only a few units off from each other. I can conclude only that SO puts questions and answers in the same table. What is the advantage of doing it this way?

I would have put questions and answers in different tables, and used foreign keys in the answers table to refer back to the question table. Can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score -2):

If stack overflow uses oracle they might have just shared a common sequence.  Or perhaps they use a different method of generating IDs.  Perhaps the IDs are generated by a service and put into the database.

Comment: I think they settled on a Microsoft stack since that's what they knew best.

Comment: The database schema has been posted numerous places including the SO blog, Meta and SO itself. Have a look at http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Understanding_the_StackOverflow_Database_Schema